# Can't make fancybox work

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've got a problem with my "FancyBox".
I can't trigger it, insted it opens my "iframe" in another window.
I've even tried to copy the code from another threat: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917696/getting-fancybox-to-work)

But I really just can't make it work, what am I doing wrong???
Can anyone help me, as I really need to make this work before monday.. :(

Here's my code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>ESTV | TV- og Videoproduktion</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css"/>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.0" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.0"></script>


</head>

<body>
```

And when I call it, I do it like this:

```
<a class="info" class="various" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/iframe.html">Læs mere</a>
```

Comment: Don't: `class="info" class="various"`. Do: `class="info various"`

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialised the fancybox. You need something along the lines of this:

```
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        $('a.info').fancybox();
    });
</script>
```